# Picking and posting multiple pics and vids using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In social media apps such as Instagram you can often publish a post with multiple pics and vids. In flutter there are couple of dependencies such as image/video picker which allow you to choose a single image or a single video, and a file manager dependency which allows you to pic multiple pics but no videos. Is there a dependency where we can pick multiple pics and vids and publish them as one post?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workflow of what you should do:

1. Add image_picker plugin in pubspec.yaml;
2. Add Requied Permissions if any;
3. Call ImagePicker.pick* and this will return you a file;
4. Display your file or perform the action you needed.